# Transfer magento project one domain to other and getting issues

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, customer-account

I transferred my project one domain to other one after that i change baseurl(secure/unsecure) in table **core_config_data** and delete cache folder and removing all sessions and locks too.

My project works but i am getting error on checkout page get error no cms page found 404 error. its also for customer account page also.

Can any one have idea why this happen how can solve it.

Comment: have you checked log and reports files?

Comment: Go to `app/etc/local.xml` and rename it as `local.xml__`. And then try to install the project again.

Comment: My project has many extension & product data..due to this can loosing data ? i think so you told me about mangeto re-install am i right ?

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions from my side:

- Check your `exception.log` and `system.log` in `var/log` directory: Any new entries?
- Check errors in `var/report` directory: Any new files?
- Run re-indexing
- Check HTTP Response with tools like firebug (network tab): What HTTP Response do you get? Maybe you'll see a redirect inbetween?
- Clear cache once more ;-)
- Delete your browser history, maybe try another browser where there's no content cached yet.
- Check `.htaccess`: Are there any entries related to your old domain?

I just wrote an answer not so long ago on how to move a shop to another server. Don't know if you just changed your domain or also the server, but here's the link: [How to move magento shop to another server](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/22130/231)