# Moving Magento webshop to new server

Tags: server-setup, hosting

I need help with the process moving a live magento shop to a new server/host. I received all the magento files from the current host of the webshop some weeks ago.. Still trying to figure out the process of how to do it.

I have setup a new server, uploading all files I received and uploading the database. But how is the process now? What happend with the orders and new customers since I received the files in october? Can someone please tell me the way to go, so the transfer will be withhout problems and without loss of data?

After all is setting up, I will change the nameservers where the domain is now to my new server. I also have the magento admin access to the existing server.

Thanks.

Comment: See this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22120/how-to-move-magento-shop-to-another-server/22130#22130 and my answer here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/22130/231

Comment: OMG, you said it is a live shop, all you have to do, on Friday lower your DNS ttl, Saturday night enable maintenance mode, just rsync and mysqldump.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are a little out of your depth with the process so I would advise you to contact an experienced Magento professional to help you directly, for example a lot of specialist Magento web hosts will usually be able to offer some form of migration service when you take one of their Magento hosting packages.

However if that's not possible then [here is a link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server) to the official Wiki on the process.