# Move magento site with redis to server without redis how to disable redis

Tags: redis

I want to copy a Magento site with Redis cache to another server without Redis. Is this possible with just the steps as [described here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/22130/17064)?

Probably that's not enough because it is looking for Redis which is not there.

**Edit**
I followed the instruction of seanbreeden, but that gives me an error:
`Connection to Redis failed after 2 failures.`

Below my `local.xml` file

```
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date><![CDATA[Tue, 11 Mar 2014 20:31:26 +0000]]></date>
        </install>
        <crypt>
            <key><![CDATA[xxxxxxxxx]]></key>
        </crypt>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
                <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[magento]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[xxxxx]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[db_magento]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
        <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>  
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

And `app/etc/modules/Cm_RedisSession.xml`

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Cm_RedisSession>
      <active>false</active>
      <codePool>community</codePool>
    </Cm_RedisSession>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, with the additional step of removing the lines in `app/etc/local.xml` that involve Redis and removing any Redis extensions that you have installed.  Most likely, the only one you'd have will be `Cm_RedisSession`.  You can disable that extension by editing the `app/etc/modules/Cm_RedisSession.xml` file and changing the enabled node from `true` to `false`.

Your `app/etc/local.xml` should look similar to this on your new site:

```
<config>
<global>
<install>
  <date><![CDATA[Thu, 1 Jan 2015 19:00:00 +0000]]></date>
</install>
<crypt>
  <key><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]]></key>
</crypt>
<disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
<resources>
  <db>
    <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
  </db>
  <default_setup>
    <connection>
      <host><![CDATA[DATABASE_HOST]]></host>
      <username><![CDATA[USERNAME]]></username>
      <password><![CDATA[PASSWORD]]></password>
      <dbname><![CDATA[DATABASE_NAME]]></dbname>
      <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
      <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
      <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
      <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
      <active>1</active>
    </connection>
  </default_setup>
</resources>
<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
</global>
<admin>
<routers>
  <adminhtml>
    <args>
      <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
    </args>
  </adminhtml>
  </routers>
</admin>
</config>
```

Comment: Oké, I will try this!

Comment: Hmm, not working! It tells me `Connection to Redis failed after 2 failures.` My `Cm_RedisSession.xml` file contains `<config>
  <modules>
    <Cm_RedisSession>
      <active>false</active>
      <codePool>community</codePool>
    </Cm_RedisSession>
  </modules>
</config>
`

Comment: Do you have session save set to "files"?

`<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>`

Comment: Yes I did do that. Parts of the /admin are working, but some parts give the same error. But the site itself is not working at all and throwing that error.

Comment: Are there any other xml files in app/etc? If any of them have redis entries then move them out of that folder. Be sure to flush your cache as well.

Comment: YES, there was an fpc.xml as wel that caused this. Renamed the file, flushed all the cache and now it is working! Thanks!

Comment: Ah! looks like any file ending with .xml shouldn't have redis config. Renamed culprit file and back to business now :-)

Comment: @Timo002 rename the fpc.xml doesn't work for me, but remove it does.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that making sure there are no other .xml file in app/etc that contain redis configuration such as old local.old.xml or fpc.old.xml.  The system will still use these files for configuration and detect redis configuration in them.

Comment: I found this cache file in `lib\Cm\Cache\Backend`.

Answer (score 0):

When installing on a server with SeLinux check SeLinux is not blocking the connection to the Redis server. On my new server SeLinux was enforcing. When SeLinux was disabled, everything worked fine.

You can check /var/log/audit/audit.log for SeLinux error messages.