# After configuring live site on my localhost(Xampp) getting error

Tags: magento-1.9

Please visit here to see the issue :-

http://nimb.ws/3hQZbP

On my live site memcache, Redis etc was running, to remove this settings for my localhost i've modified app/etc/local.xml.
I've also take a fresh .htaccess file, removed var folder still getting same problem.

here is my local.xml :- 
====================Start of local.xml==============

```
<config>
    <global>
    <install>
        <date><![CDATA[Tue, 19 Jan 2016 05:05:05 +0000]]></date>
    </install>
    <crypt>
        <key><![CDATA[cd6448749aa393de861a60b125221c15]]></key>
    </crypt>
    <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
    <resources>
        <db>
            <table_prefix><![CDATA[mg]]></table_prefix>
        </db>
        <default_setup>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[benoit2]]></dbname>
                <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </default_setup>
    </resources>
    <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
    </global>
    <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <frontName><![CDATA[storeadmin]]></frontName>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

===============End of local.xml===================

Thanks in advance...!!!

Comment: I hope [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54212/move-magento-site-with-redis-to-server-without-redis-how-to-disable-redis) may help you

Comment: try to disable redis extensions that you have installed.

Comment: didn't install any redis ext., Cm_RedisSession.xml is already disabled.

Comment: Finally I got the solution, actually  on the live site i've used redis cache but when i setup live site on my localhost then i rename local.xml to local_live.xml & configure a new fresh local.xml for my localhost.so i should  rename local.xml to local.xml++ instead of local_live.xml because  Magento was calling always  local_live.xml also that's why i was getting this issue.