# Magento migration Fail (live to localhost)

Tags: magento-1.9, migration, backup

I tried to migrate/transfer my live site to localhost. I am using WAMP and I imported the database via phpmyadmin,
Problem comes up after i process the configuration process(after filling database information)

i got error **SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1022 Can't write; duplicate key in table** and error log as below:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:239:"Error in file: "C:\wamp\www\localsite\app\code\local\amam\Conf\sql\amconf_setup\mysql4-upgrade-3.2.2-3.3.0.php" - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1022 Can't write; duplicate key in table 'amam_amconf_product_attribute'";i:1;s:940:"#0 C:\wamp\www\localsite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 C:\wamp\www\localsite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.0.0', '3.9.11')
#2 C:\wamp\www\localsite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.0.0', '3.9.11')
#3 C:\wamp\www\localsite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 C:\wamp\www\localsite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 C:\wamp\www\localsite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 C:\wamp\www\localsite\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 C:\wamp\www\localsite\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:11:"/localsite/";s:11:"script_name";s:20:"/localsite/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

where "amam" is an extension folder name.
Thanks for anyone trying to help!

Comment: As this error is thrown within an upgrade script: Did you clear the cache inbetween and reload the page?

Comment: And check out this question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22120/how-to-move-magento-shop-to-another-server and  http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/22130/231

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: 
Spent days to find that the problem is JUST - u need **correct data in app/ect/local.xml** (i.e. admin_name, database_name..etc) but NOT to delete it!

If you deleted the local.xml, the magento installation process will run (so yo u can fill in admin and database info), but at the same time **it also create unnecessary tables**
i.e. my original table is ***xgj_core_config_data*** (dunno why there are prefix), but the process also created the default ones: ***core_config_data*** (without the prefix), which finally leads the duplicate keys error.

Answer (score 1):

Basically when you migrate a site and want to change the domain for the site, there's a couple things that you need to do.

For starters, let's say you're going from mysite.com to local.mysite.com (that way if you've got a wildcard SSL cert you can still use it locally).  Assuming you've got Apache all set up for local.mysite.com, what you need to do in Magento is

1) `Update the DB parameters and if necessary`, your `redis/memcache` parameters in local.xml.  While you *could* delete local.xml and rerun the installation, it's a text file so you can just edit the fields and you're golden.  For me, I have to strip out all the Redis caching/session stuff since I don't have a local Redis instance and then update the DB host settings.

2) Log into the DB that you're local installation is going to use and run

SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE value like '%mysite%';

I like to do it with the wildcards just so that I can see what all is tied to the mysite.com domain.  But you should see in your search results a couple lines where the path column is `web/unsecure/base_url` and we`b/secure/base_url`.  Then you'll need to update those lines to 'http://local.mysite.com/' and 'https://local.mysite.com/' respectively.  Don't forget the trailing slash though!

3) Flush your cache.  This could be anything from deleting the contents of `var/cache and var/session to flushing memcache or redis as appropriate`.

And that should be it.  Point a browser to `local.mysite.com` (assuming, if needed, that you've got a hosts file entry that points local.mysite.com to 127.0.0.1) and your site should load on your new local installation!