# Moved Magento to new server and Front end users can't login

Tags: customer, login, migration

I moved my Magento installation from a production server to my dev machine. I have the host mapped to dev.local/my site. Copied the DB as well and changed the URL references. I have done everything listed here =>[https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22120/how-to-move-magento-shop-to-another-server#*=*](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22120/how-to-move-magento-shop-to-another-server#_=_)

Everything appears to work and I can login to the admin side just fine but the weird part is I can't login to the store(frontend) using the test customer credentials I use in production. Resetting the password on the admin side for that user fixes the issue, but that's really not an option for me since I hope to do a migration to a different server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it has something to do with the same user email existing on the admin side was well as the customer side. I tried a customer specific account and that appeared to work correctly.