# Not able to set up site clone on WAMP

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to clone my server to my WAMP for testing purposes.

I have copied all of the server files to my `www/storename` folder.

I have imported the database to `phpMyAdmin`.

And I have followed this [tutorial](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/22130/51693).

But when I go to `http://localhost/storename` I just see my folder structure.

Comment: Compare your files in Magento root folder, maybe you missed some index.php or htaccess  https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror?files=1

Comment: You were correct, I was missing the index.php, thanks! Put it in an answer and I will accept it;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare your files in Magento root folder, maybe you missed some index.php or htaccess

Last version of magento 1.9:

[github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror?files=1](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror?files=1)